# Calculating with time differences

Tags: java

Obviously, there are already threads about calculating with time in Java.

However, my question goes a little bit further.
What I want to do:

- Calculating difference between beginning and ending time (ALREADY DONE)
- Adding this difference back to the beginning time

An example:
Paul started working at 4:00 and ended at 9:00 
I want it to return 6:30 (4 + (9-4)/2)

My code yet:

```
for (int i = 1, n = licenseplateList.size(); i < n; i++) 
{               
    //first look at whether it is considered as day or night time               
    try {
    String time1 = begintimeList.get(i);
    String time2 = endingtimeList.get(i);

    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
    Date date1 = format.parse(time1);
    Date date2 = format.parse(time2);
    long average = ((date2.getTime() - date1.getTime())/2);

    System.out.println(average);


    }catch (Exception e) {
    }
```

Edit:
I also want to know how I afterwards can decide whether it's day or night time (i want to use beginning + ending, because if that's over 18:00 I'll consider it nigh time). However, how can I do this in an ifstatement?

Comment: You have time1 and time2, you get the difference, and then add it to time1 to get time2? How is that 6:30?

Comment: Your maths have a problem, namely, the fact that: A - B + A = B

Comment: Ah ye gotcha i obviously mean that it is 9-4 as explained about thats 5, devided by 2 is 6:30

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sort of calculations is easier using (not so new) Java 8 time api

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String time1Str = "04:00";
    String time2Str = "09:00";

    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm");
    LocalTime time1 = LocalTime.parse(time1Str, formatter);
    LocalTime time2 = LocalTime.parse(time2Str, formatter);
    Duration duration = Duration.between(time1, time2);  // 9-4
    Duration halfDuration = duration.dividedBy(2);  // divided by 2
    LocalTime result = LocalTime.from(halfDuration.addTo(time1));  // added to start time

    System.out.println(result.format(formatter));
}
```

**EDIT: support ranges that cross date boundary**
in this case, we need to add date value to the times. this will tell Java that the range 22:00 to 01:00 is about "tomorow":

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String time1Str = "22:00";
    String time2Str = "01:00";

    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm");
    LocalTime time1 = LocalTime.parse(time1Str, formatter);
    LocalTime time2 = LocalTime.parse(time2Str, formatter);

    // add date value: start with today
    LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
    // combine date time for lower value: will be assigned to today
    LocalDateTime dateTime1 = LocalDateTime.of(today, time1);
    // combine date time for upper value: will be assigned same day if it is after lower value
    // otherwise (we crossed date boundary) assign it to tomorrow
    LocalDateTime dateTime2 =   time2.isAfter(time1) ?
            LocalDateTime.of(today, time2) : LocalDateTime.of(today.plusDays(1), time2);

    Duration duration = Duration.between(dateTime1, dateTime2);
    Duration halfDuration = duration.dividedBy(2);
    LocalTime result = LocalTime.from(halfDuration.addTo(time1));

    System.out.println(result.format(formatter));
}
```

Comment: Nice one! but 22:14 till 00:34 now returns 11:24 ... How to solve that problem?

Comment: if the answer was helpful, i'd appreciate accepting and upvoting.

Comment: and how would i now say like "if result.format(formatter) < 06:00 || result.format(formatter) > 17:30 "

Comment: yes i did it, but it needs approval cuz i have only like 10 reputation :P

Comment: to compare `localTime` values you can use `isAfter()` and `isBefore()`. have a look at the javadoc, or the official [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)

Comment: yes i have found that i should be able to do this boolean before = result.format(formatter).before("6:00");
     
     
     if (before == true) {

Comment: also imported the right thing, but it says cannot find symbol (because of type string i think)

Comment: yes, you need to first convert the string to `LocalTime`

Comment: nah cuz it also says symbol is not found for before(LocalTime) but i swear ive read it here https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/date_before.htm

Comment: you are not dealing with `java.util.Date` anymore.

Comment: what do you mean by that, i have imported it

Comment: take a look at the class names I use in my answer

Comment: could you please help ive been trying for hours nowalready lol https://pastebin.com/qsBRRs0n

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#isBefore-java.time.LocalTime-